# Why and how does this strange method return type compile?

Tags: java, language-lawyer

The following method has a return type of `int[][]`. Note how one of the `[]`'s are on the right hand side of the `()`'s.

Why does this work and what is this behavior called?

```
int[] numbers () [] {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I call it "extremely ugly confusing code"

Comment: "Just because you can doesn't mean you should"

Comment: How this is called: "// Yechh!"  Java Language Specification [Array Variables and Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-10.html#d5e18163) (5th *screen*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)

> The declaration of a method that returns an array is allowed to place some or all of the bracket pairs that denote the array type after the formal parameter list. This syntax is supported for compatibility with early versions of the Java programming language. It is very strongly recommended that this syntax is not used in new code.

Comment: but also [10.2. Array Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2): 'We do not recommend "mixed notation" in array variable declarations, where bracket pairs appear on both the type and in declarators; nor in method declarations, where bracket pairs appear both before and after the formal parameter list.'